# How can I make GnuCash to use fractions instead of decimals for dollar amounts?

Tags: mutual-funds, price

In a Mutual Fund "Account Type", I enter an "Income Dividend" transaction of 0.482 shares with a value of $403.72. GnuCash converts this to $403.7137. Behind the scenes, it appears to be using 403 + 172/241, but this is less accurate than 403 + 72/100. How can I convince GnuCash to use 403.72 or 403 + 72/100? I'm using version 4.8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/1565735/gnucash-4-0-displays-price-as-ratio-rather-than-decimal

Comment: Thanks, but no. That dealt with the display of the value, not the inaccuracy of the fraction chosen by GnuCash.

Comment: This looks like standard mathematical roundoff error. Binary fractions do round off differently than decimals, and virtually nobody even considers trying to maintain decimal fractions in a program. Speaking as a programmer, I would say only GnuCash's authors can change this, and it would be a huge amount of effort to do so for something which is, arguably, not much more than cosmetic.

Comment: It's probably /256 or something like that, not /241.. As I said, binary math rather than decimal math. (There was a time when the big IBM machines could do math in Binary Counted Decimal, just to get roundoffs that looked more natural to humans. But that cost a significant amount of additional computing power and fell out of use .)

Comment: If I uncheck "Force Prices to display as decimals, it shows 403 + 172/241. If I use a simple 8-bit binary fraction, I can get 0.71875, which is closer than .7137. Can someone point me to a reference that explains how GnuCash is storing numbers internally?

Comment: https://github.com/Gnucash/gnucash has the full source code. That's the reference for internal behavior. (Is it *really* using a Rational Numbers math package internally and storing fractions? Not impossible but I'd be rather startled and somewhat dismayed.)

Comment: FWIW, The usual practice is to store the total price and number of shares as fixed-precision numbers (sunce those are known exactly) and calculate effective price per share from them, rounding off.  Going the other way can produce some artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used gnucash. The thing you need to know is how many decimal places the brokerage uses.

> In a Mutual Fund "Account Type", I enter an "Income Dividend"
> transaction of 0.482 shares with a value of $403.72.

The company declares a dividend of 0.xx per share. The brokerage multiples this number by the number of shares you own, which is a cash value. They then either put the cash rounded to cents into your sweep account, or if they use it to purchase additional shares. Again this is is tracked at the precision they normally use. The thing to check is do they round before purchasing new shares.

When entering 2 parts of a 3 part equation, and you get a strange result in the value you didn't enter; I always suspect that the wrong pair of values were picked to enter.

Comment: My statement from the broker says Quantity is 0.4820, Price is 403.7200, and Amount is 194.50. When I type the 1st two into GnuCash, GC converts 403.72 to 403.7137 and calculates the Buy as 194.59. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like the numbers from your broker are confusing. They show 0.4820 shares but that is only true if they round to three significant figures, then tack on a zero at the end to make it look nice.